# Is there a way to obtain Khadgar, while I know no one owning a osx device?

Tags: hearthstone

Question title pretty much says it.
Are there ways to buy the new hearthstone hero skin for Khadgar, which is limited to the purchase through apple store and just available to april the 24th, without buying a Ipad/Iphone, in case I know no one else owning one?

Comment: Not a satisfying solution but has evidently be done: https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/4etpsq/if_youfriend_dont_own_an_ios_device_use_one_at_a/

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355: this is offtopic but maybe you can tell me anyway: Am I right apple store requires me to have an creditcard? No other payment methods like googleplay cards? :o Otherwise I'd even consider this as an answer ^^

Comment: Yes there are cards like Google Play Cards. I just tested it, you can buy inside the hearthstone app with the credit from your card.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think there is. It is a joint offer with Apple and WWF that has made a campaign with a lot of other software developers for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Using an android emulator worked for the S5 promotion, but this will not work here as this promotion requires access to the store. No emulator can access the store this way.

You'll need to buy, borrow, or rent an Apple device.